# Which language to use for an European brand name?

Tags: branding

This is a UX question as the brand name initially (=when unknown) diverges a first feeling about a company.

We have a Slovak company that is has what a single keyword about what we are doing inside it's name in the Slovak language.

The keyword is also used in our Slovak domain name and as far as I know the word is specific enough and is free in other languages.

The question is if we should re-brand to an foreign (=English) name or keep using our local brand name and push it to foreign markets (with the risk of the word being mis-written).

Can you share any case studies about brand names?

Comment: This is quite literally an English or Marketing question as you are asking about how to name your company using a specific voice or tone that will work in localized context.

Comment: While brand strategy can certainly be a part of UX, as Pxdx states, it's really the domain of marketing and design. Might be worth asking on graphicdesign.se

Comment: True, it's also a marketing design question - but having a good brand name that can be easily remembered and used later to acces your service is UX - it's like naming a button - the right words get you more clicks and more conversions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been cases of companies which have re-branded their names in local markets to reach out to new customers so that they can relate to the brand in the local language. To quote this [article](http://blog.globalizationpartners.com/branding-usability-localization.aspx)

> It is true that when the original brand names are short and simple, it
>   is sometimes a good choice to keep them as is instead of translating
>   them. Companies like Sony, Google, Intel, they have kept the same name
>   in multiple countries. But as each country, culture and language is
>   beautiful and unique in its own way, it will be incorrect to assume
>   the same name will be appropriate or the best options for all target
>   locales. Some of the best examples are companies such as Coca-Cola,
>   Sprite, and PizzaHut branding localized into Chinese.
>
> The Chinese branding for Coca-Cola is 可口可樂 (Simplified Chinese is 可口可乐
>   ) The direct translation for the first two characters  可口 is
>   "delicious". The last two characters "可樂" mean "able to enjoy". In
>   addition, this term has become official translation for "Coke" for all
>   brands. This great branding localization not only has positive
>   meaning, but just like its original brand name, is easy to pronounce
>   and hard to forget. This branding also enhances their advertising
>   effectiveness and tagline creativity. Another great example is
>   "Sprite". Its Chinese name is "雪碧" (Traditional and Simplified Chinese
>   share identical characters). "雪" means "snow", and "碧" is either an
>   adjective or noun for blue or blue-green. This combination brings the
>   feeling of icy-coldness and freshness, and the meaning of "碧" also
>   resonates for its green packaging. The pronunciation of the Chinese
>   brand is also very similar to the English name.

I also recommend looking at this excellent but hilarious article about [some brand names which dont translate well](http://www.deseretnews.com/article/700078810/Some-brand-names-dont-translate-well.html?pg=all). To quote a part of the article

> For example, an Iranian company named Paxan Corp. currently produces a
>   line of soaps and detergents under the name "Barf." This word has a
>   positive and clean meaning of "snow" in Iran, but what English speaker
>   would ever choose to use a cleaning product with this brand? Likewise,
>   if the Japanese sports drink "Pocari Sweat" were exported to the
>   United States, how many English speakers would choose to drink
>   "Sweat"?

I also [recommend looking at this interesting case study](http://home.ku.edu.tr/~globalbrand/files/Yang_and_Chattopadhyay.pdf) where it looks at the impact of rebranding your name with the country as a prefix (e.g. Microsoft to Microsoft China)